# Does the player always move first?

Tags: nethack

In Nethack, does the player always move first, or is there a chance other monsters/NPCs/entities might?

To be specific... Say we are in a small room. Player on one side, a gobbo on another. There is exactly one tile of space between them. The player decides to move toward the gobbo. Goblin moves toward the player.

Is there any way or chance that the gobbo will move in that tile before the player?

Comment: There is a wait command, which makes you stand still for a turn, though I suppose you're still "moving' first.

Comment: I believe when the game is ready for input it's always your turn and you will move.  However, once you've made your move, I believe monsters may get more than one depending on relative speed stats.

Comment: @agent86 - that's true; in addition, if your own speed is high enough, you can get multiple turns before the monster gets a single move.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, to answer the question in the title.

No, to answer the question at the end of your post.

NetHack is effectively turn-based. You perform your action, other entities in the game perform theirs.